# angular13: drag and drop not working on grid

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, grid, draggable

I have a web page of a card game, I implement fxLayout.xs and the list of cards is seen in grids, but the drag on drop does not work correctly.

html hand component

```
<div class="mano">
  <div
    fxLayout="row wrap"
    fxLayoutAlign="center"
    fxLayoutGap="10px"
    cdkDropList
    id="listaMano"
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
    [cdkDropListData]="cartasEnMano"
    cdkDropListConnectedTo="listaCampo"
  >
    <div
      fxFlex="12"
      fxLayoutGap="10px"
      fxFlex.xs="30"
      cdkDrag
      *ngFor="let carta of cartasEnMano"
      (click)="JugarCarta(carta, cartasEnMano)"
      class="objetoCarta"
    >
      <app-carta-en-mano [carta]="carta"></app-carta-en-mano>
    </div>
  </div>
```

TS hand component

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Carta[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

html game component

```
<app-oponente></app-oponente>

<div
  fxLayout="row wrap"
  fxLayoutAlign="center"
  cdkDropList
  id="listaCampo"
  (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)"
  [cdkDropListData]="cartamia"
  [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="['listaCampo']"
  class="lista"
>
  <div fxFlex="20" fxFlex.xs="30" *ngFor="let carta of cartasEnCampo" cdkDrag>
    <app-cartas-en-juego [carta]="carta"></app-cartas-en-juego>
  </div>

  <div class="contenedorBoton">
    <button
      mat-button
      (click)="combate()"
      class="boton"
      *ngIf="cartasEnCampo.length === 2"
    >
      Comenzar Combate
    </button>
    <p-toast position="top-center"> </p-toast>
  </div>
</div>

<app-mano></app-mano>
```

TS game component

```
drop(event: CdkDragDrop<Carta[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else if (this.CartasService.cartaMia === undefined) {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );}}
```

I used this solution to guide me  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xtyzts but I found two problems.

1 - when you move the cards sometimes it stops allowing to move them.

2 - based on the example in the link, I don't know how to send a card to another cdkDropList (game component), since the transferArrayItem function doesn't send the correct data

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#transferring-items-between-lists) is an example for multiple lists (official docs).

HTML

```
<div class="example-container">
  <h2>To do</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #todoList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="todo"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[doneList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="example-container">
  <h2>Done</h2>

  <div
    cdkDropList
    #doneList="cdkDropList"
    [cdkDropListData]="done"
    [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[todoList]"
    class="example-list"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, transferArrayItem} from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

/**
 * @title Drag&Drop connected sorting
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example',
  templateUrl: 'cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['cdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css'],
})
export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingExample {
  todo = ['Get to work', 'Pick up groceries', 'Go home', 'Fall asleep'];

  done = ['Get up', 'Brush teeth', 'Take a shower', 'Check e-mail', 'Walk dog'];

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Additional: cdkDrag is not so good for grids. You can use my library to sorting inside a drag. [Ngx-explorer-dnd](https://github.com/Flo0806/ngx-explorer-dnd) is inspired from `cdkDrag` and still under development and available in a alpha (at this time)

A [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsegkg?file=src/app/app.component.ts) example is available, too.

[image]